# I installed Bootstrap 4 for my Angular 11 Project but it does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I installed Bootstrap 4 for my Angular 11 project with `npm install bootstrap`

And then I configure the `angular.json` and added this:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.scss"
]
```

And in my app.component.html I tried to add a bootstrap container with row and col like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        One of three columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But nothing changed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also need to import script files.

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```